# 0 byte Zip-Archive

Tags: python, flask, zip

I have a list of URLs which contain Word documents and PDF documents. 
I want to get all of these and create a zip file containing all the documents, which then can be downloaded (Creating a Flask Response with application/zip mime-type). 
I have the following code, which only returns a 0 byte zip-file:

```
allLinks = [...]
for link in allLinks:
with zipfile.ZipFile('Documents.zip', mode='w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zip:
   response = requests.get(link, headers=headers, stream=True)
   filename = urllib.parse.unquote(response.headers.get('content-  disposition').replace("attachment; filename*=UTF-8",                                                                                     "").replace("''", "").encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8'))
if response.status_code == 200:
   zip.writestr(filename, response.content)    
return zip
```

The zip-file is not containing any thing. I thing the return statement is forwarded to quickly. I have though using threading, but I am not quite sure if this is the solution and how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting each iteration pening with  `mode='w'` so if the last url does not return 200 you get an empty zip file, st best you just get the last `zip.writestr`.

Open outside the loop:

```
allLinks = [...]
with zipfile.ZipFile('Documents.zip', mode='w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zp:
    for link in allLinks:
```

Comment: Thank you. But I still get a 0-byte archive. It dosen't seem like all the links get loaded and the documents zipped. If I am lucky it manages to zip only one document out of all the links.